# Render multiple mapbox maps with svelte leads to strage behaviour (renders but not draggable)

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox, svelte

I have this mapboxmap.svelte component (its a public token!):

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import mapbox from "mapbox-gl";
  //   import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";

  mapbox.accessToken =
    "pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9iaW5rb2hycyIsImEiOiJjanU5am95bm4xZnZ6NDNrOTRyYTYwdzJzIn0.iMFQgQIlhz36wB3819Xftw";

  // create map
  let map;
  onMount(() => {
    map = new mapbox.Map({
      container: "map", // container id
      style: "mapbox://styles/examples/cjgioozof002u2sr5k7t14dim", // map style URL from Mapbox Studio
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="map" />

<style lang="scss">
  #map {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
  }
</style>
```

And I want to render it multiple times on the site. So I import the component into my `App.svelte`-component and "call" the component two times like this:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import Mapboxmap from "./lib/maps/mapboxmap.svelte";
</script>

<Mapboxmap />
<Mapboxmap />
```

It does show two maps. Yet **only one is working** in the sense that it is draggable (this first one)

The strange this is that uncommenting this line, which imports some mapbox css

```
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
```

leads to the disappearing of the second map. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: I'm assuming it has something to do with using the same id for both maps.

Comment: that looks promising!:) Thank you:):)